# Is there always a zero of this polynomial that is not a root of unity?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots-of-unity

Consider the polynomial $1-z(1+z)^a$ with $a$ a positive integer. Is there always a complex zero of this polynomial that is not a root of unity?

I tried to prove it by induction or by contradiction but I didn't succeed.

Comment: When you write "complex zero", do you exclude real zeros?

Comment: no, if there is a real zero different from -1 or +1 then that would be good. So I guess that if $a$ is even then the problem is solved. But what if $a$ is odd?

Comment: ah but there is always a real root. Sorry this problem is easier than I thought.